# Hibernate Search 5.5.2 - Poor peformance of index update on objects with many associations

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I'm running into serious performance issues with Hibernate Search. It seems when I save/update/remove an entity that is referenced via @IndexedEmbedded or @ContainedIn - the parent indexed entity goes through a complete initialisation of all lazy collections that are part of the index graph. In some cases this is 1000s of associated objects being initialised and fetched from the database. I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour, but I would imagine only the field that is being updated/added needs to be updated/added in the index, and don't see why my lazy collections need to be initialised.

Here is the simplified code showing how I've set up the entities and search graph:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Profile {

    @Id
    public int id;
    @Field
    public String name;

    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = "name")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Profile parentProfile;

    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentProfile")
    public Set<Profile> childrenProfiles = new HashSet<Profile>();

    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "id.userId" })
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile")
    public Set<AdminMap> adminMap = new HashSet<AdminMap>();

    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "id.userId" })
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile")
    public Set<FavouritesMap> favouritesMap = new HashSet<FavouritesMap>();

}

@Indexed
@Entity
public class BusinessProfile extends Profile {...}

@Indexed
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends Profile {...}

@Entity
public class FavouritesMap {

    @EmbeddedId
    @IndexedEmbedded
    public FavouritesMapId id;

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Profile profile;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public User user;

}

@Embeddable
public class FavouritesMapId {

    @Field
    public int userId;
    public int profileId;
}
```

So we have a Profile entity, which can have 1 parent and many children. A Profile also has a set of users that are administrators for the profile (adminMap), and a set of users that have favourite'd that profile (favouritesMap). I've included the FavouritesMap entity class and associated id class, the AdminMap follows the same structure. The Profile entity is not directly indexed, but it's extended types are.

This is the code for when a user does the action of 'favouriting' a profile:

```
public FavouritesMap setAsFavourite(int userId, int profileId) {
    FavouritesMap fav = new FavouritesMap(new FavouritesMapId(userId, profileId));

    Profile profile = (Profile)entityManager.findById(Profile.class, profileId);
    fav.setProfile(profile);

    entityManager.save(fav);

    return fav;
}
```

What I would expect to happen is that when we call entityManager.save(fav), hibernate search sees the @ContainedIn field 'profile', looks up the index for that profile item, and just adds the new field (favouritesMap.id.userId) to that profile item in the index.

However what appears to be happening is that hibernate search is initialising all of the collections (adminMap, favouritesMap and childrenProfiles) in the profile entity. Which in some of my cases results in 1000's of associated entities being fetched, causing huge performance issues. This is evidenced as the method setAsFavourite is returning a FavouritesMap object with the profile field's collections all fully initialised. If I remove the hibernate search annotations, then the object is correctly returning unintialised lazy collections, suggesting it's a hibernate search issue.

So my question is, is this the correct behaviour for hibernate search to initialise all these lazy collections and reindex all fields when adding an item via a @ContainedIn reference? If so, ...why? surely it just needs to add that one new field rather than revalidate the entire index for that entity. If not, is there any obvious errors with my setup, or how may I best debug this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct, and the short answer is: this is required.

The Lucene Document needs to be re-written entirely for any update, even if only one field changed.

Remember that Lucene is not a relational database: you can't update just one "column" but it requires you to write the Document again, essentially delete the previous one and re-insert a fresh copy.

It is not possible to read the existing document, as indexing is often not a bi-directional transformation, that would require to mark all your fields as "stored" - which is not desirable from a performance perspective either. Even if you were to mark all fields as stored, it would still not be safe to read the index Document because of re-ordering of operations and would possibly introduce inconsistencies in the final index state.

Hibernate Search includes strategies for "dirty checking" which go beyond the ones applied by Hibernate ORM: we try hard to figure if an index update can not be skipped, but if a write needs to happen then indeed the full graph needs to be read to produce a fresh Document.

Besides trying to limit the depth of recursive fields which get indexed, a common technique is to enable 2nd level caching and make sure to enable it extensively on frequently read associations.

Not least, make sure to clearly delimit the object graph that you actually need indexed by using options such as:

- `@IndexedEmbedded`(**includePaths**)
- `@IndexedEmbedded`(**depth**)

*The defaults might be indexing more branches than what you actually need.*

In future we plan to be able to "break up" the Document in two parts by using explicit index-time joins, but even when we'll do this you will need to keep this limitation in mind, as Lucene doesn't support the same kind of joins that a relational database could provide: we'll likely be able to  split a Document only at one specific point (only one join can be considered).

Comment: thanks for the response, though it wasn't quite the response I hoped for! A  couple follow-on questions, is there a way to make the re-indexing operation be threaded so that my application doesn't have to wait for it to complete? And is there any recommended alternative method for filtering search results, based on data that isn't part of the index? Eg, in my case where a Profile could potentially have millions of Favourites, it's not feasible to keep those associations in the search index, yet the user still needs to be able to filter search results by those Favourites

Comment: the indexing operations can't be moved to a background thread as that would make us load data in a different transaction. About recommendations.. there are many "tricks" which you can think of, probably best to get back to the Hibernate forums to speak of details!